# Duplicating layer in memory using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, copy, memory, duplication

I have a layer in QGIS, and I want to duplicate it through a plugin so I can use the copy of it as I want, without modifying the original.

Of course `layer2 = layer1` will not work, because everything that happens to layer2 will also happen to layer1, as it is the same object behind all this.

The only way I found to do it is as such:

```py
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1, r"C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\NewLayer.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\NewLayer.shp", "New vector", "ogr")
#do something with layer2
```

Is there a simple way to duplicate the layer in memory, without having to write a new file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code works for me from both the Python Console and plugin. It takes the features from the source input layer and copies the attributes to a memory layer (in this case, a polygon layer but you can change it to `LineString` or `Point` depending on layer type):

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/layer", "polygon", "ogr")
feats = [feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()]

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "duplicated_layer", "memory")

mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
attr = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
mem_layer.updateFields()
mem_layer_data.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Comment: Alright I knew this one, I just find it a bit long (in terms of lines of code). But I guess it is the only way to do it ; thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Ril8772 - Most welcome! Not sure if it is the only way but it's the only way I know =)

Answer (score 22):

In QGIS 3 you can make a copy of a layer without saving any reference to the parent layer in this way:

```py
layer.selectAll()
clone_layer = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT': layer, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
layer.removeSelection()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clone_layer)
```

The [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) class has a [`clone()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aa2fd518bbe4e03d7feb668f5774af4f3) method that allows you to clone the layer in a new layer, the problem is that if you modify the geometry in the cloned layer the original layer will be affected: the reason for this is that the data source is the same for the original layer and the cloned layer.

Comment: Work great. Just wanted to add that with `layer.removeSelection()` the Selection can removed again after the cloning and with `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(clone_layer)` the cloned layer can be added to the map

Comment: Great @Jonathan. I've already updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to use the [`materialize()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureSource.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureSource.materialize) method from the [`QgsFeatureSource`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureSource.html#module-QgsFeatureSource) class. It is available since QGIS 3.0.

### Over the entire layer with the [`allFeatureIds()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureSource.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureSource.allFeatureIds) method:

```py
#choose a layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
#or with: layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('name_of_the_layer')[0]
#create a new layer from all features   
new_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.allFeatureIds()))
#add a new layer to the map
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

### Over the selection of all features with the [`selectedFeatureIds()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.selectedFeatureIds) method from the [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html) class:

```py
#choose a layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
#or with: layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('name_of_the_layer')[0]
#select all features in the original layer
layer.selectAll()
#create a new layer from selected features
new_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.selectedFeatureIds()))
#remove selection in the original layer
layer.removeSelection()
#add a new layer to the map  
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

---

**References:**

- [Creating Vector layer from selected features with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80292/creating-vector-layer-from-selected-features-with-pyqgis)