# Is there any way to make a buffer without using the processing buffer tool in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am developing a plugin in QGIS and I was given a task to develop a plugin without using the inbuilt functions of QGIS. Now, For most of the case I have avoided using built-in modules like sum line length tools to calculate line and using the intersection.length() instead, but now I am stuck on buffer. Let's say I have a line file and I want to make a buffer around it, so I wanted to know, is there any way to make buffer in QGIS without using the buffer processing tool and completely coding it.

A buffer like the image below

I don't want to use `processing.run("native:buffer", {dict of parameters})` but I want to know is there a method to code it and not use this function.

[image]

Comment: why? is this a homework problem?

Comment: More like research study problem. Under a professor.

Comment: then the best way to learn is to try to solve it yourself instead of asking here. Feel free to come back when you have tried a solution and got stuck. Don't forget you can study the source code of QGis and other open source programs

Comment: While learning how the algorithms of GIS work *is* important, this "reinvent every wheel" approach seems... *counterproductive* (since you're also likely reinventing every defect as well).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following (after you selected a layer)

Be aware that we use as an input a layer using EPSG:4326 (hence, the buffer 0.2 degrees = around 20km depending where you are on the globe). The `buffer` function uses units from the geometry SRS. You may need to reproject (good thing to learn for your "homework")

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# layer = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/layer", "polygon", "ogr")

feats = [QgsFeature(feat) for feat in layer.getFeatures()]

new_feats = []
for feat in feats:
    geom = feat.geometry()
    feat.setGeometry(geom.buffer(0.2, 8))
    new_feats.append(feat)

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "duplicated_layer", "memory")

mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
attr = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
mem_layer.updateFields()
mem_layer_data.addFeatures(new_feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

PS: Code mainly borrowed from [Duplicating layer in memory using pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205947/duplicating-layer-in-memory-using-pyqgis) and adapted

**Edit**:

For dissolve support, you can take a look at C++ code to see how it works in original processing C++ code you try to avoid ;) https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmbuffer.cpp.

Be aware that reimplementing all the buffer functionalities in Python is a bit of a waste in fact. The processing buffer was in the "old days" in Python and to speed up has been ported in C++. So, you lose all the benefits with your approach. FYI,you can look at old code [`buffer.py`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/2d1aa68f0d044f2aced7ebeca8d2fa6b754ac970/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Buffer.py) (for QGIS 2.18)

Comment: I also wanted to implement the dissolve result feature in buffer, the way it asks on the buffer dialog box, in this code the buffer might overlap.

Comment: Edited for the "dissolve" part