# Setting selected features in list without specifying their layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, features, select-by-location, delete

To get selected features I usually do: `layer.selectedFeatures()`.

Is there a method to retrieve selected features in a list without specifying the layer they belong to ?

I selected features with the ["Selection by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) tool:

```py
processing.run("native:selectbylocation", 
                   {'INPUT': "C://path/file1.shp",
                    'PREDICATE':[0,4,7],
                    'INTERSECT':"C://path/file2.shp",
                    'METHOD':0})
```

The features I am seeking are indeed selected in my QGIS environment. Now I would like to delete them with PyQGIS but I don't know how to retrieve and put them in a list since I didn't create a `QgsVectorLayer` object for my shapefile.

Do you know a way to either retrieve the selected features or the layer they belong to ?

Comment: What is the output of the algorithm? Perhaps that will give you a clue

Comment: The output is a dict object with one key : `{"OUTPUT": "C://path/file1.shp"}`. So I tried to store that output in a QgsVectorLayer object, but there is 0 selected feature when I try to count them with `selectedFeatureCount()`. Even though the same layer already displayed in QGIS has some selected features in its attribute table.

Answer (score 5):

There are most likely several approaches to tackle your issue, but I would probably lean on @Matt's suggestion.

There is a special method for deleting selected features called [`deleteSelectedFeatures()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.deleteSelectedFeatures).

Keep in mind that the output of processing will inherit the name of your `'INPUT'` variable.

```py
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('grid_test2')[0]
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('grid_test')[0]

selection = processing.run("native:selectbylocation", 
                   {'INPUT': layer1,
                    'PREDICATE': [0,4,7],
                    'INTERSECT': layer2,
                    'METHOD':0})['OUTPUT']

layer_to_edit = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(selection.name())[0]

layer_to_edit.startEditing()
layer_to_edit.deleteSelectedFeatures()
layer_to_edit.commitChanges()
```

If you though want to retrieve a list with selected features, then try this:

```py
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('grid_test2')[0]
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('grid_test')[0]

selection = processing.run("native:selectbylocation", 
                   {'INPUT': layer1,
                    'PREDICATE': [0,4,7],
                    'INTERSECT': layer2,
                    'METHOD':0})['OUTPUT']

layer_to_edit = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(selection.name())[0]

selected_ids = [feat.id() for feat in selection.selectedFeatures()]

layer_to_edit.startEditing()
for fid in selected_ids:
    layer_to_edit.deleteFeature(fid)
layer_to_edit.commitChanges()
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 21. Cheat sheet for PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#processing-algorithms)
- [Deleting selected features using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112172/deleting-selected-features-using-pyqgis)
- [Getting attributes of selected features using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/getting-attributes-of-selected-features-using-pyqgis/421263#421263)